# Failed to set version to docker-desktop: exit code: -1

Tags: docker

Error in runing docker in windows

**InvalidOperationException:**  Failed to set version to docker-desktop: exit code: -1
stdout: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my issue by resetting Winsock (Windows Socket) Settings.
Go to powershell or cmd and run below command as administrator:

`netsh winsock reset`

and **don't** restart system as command prompt. Then you can run docker-desktop.

next time restart system run this command again to start docker-desktop.

Comment: run as administrator.

```netsh winsock reset```

and don't restart system as command prompt.

next time restart system this command run again to start docker-desktop

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me on Docker Desktop 4.7.1 with Windows10